# Passing negative values as arguments to custom management commands in django

Tags: django

Like many others, I've been learning web development on django through building a test app. I've the basic models set up. I've populated a few of the tables with the absolute minimum data needed for further testing though using fixtures.

Now for a different table, I want to create data tuples through a custom management command which takes the required arguments. If this works as expected, I'll save the created data to the database by adding the `--save` option.

The syntax of the command is like this

```
create_raw_data owner_id temperature [--save]
```

where `owner_id` is required and `temperature` (in C) is optional. Within the `Handle` method, I'm using *factory boy* to create the `raw_data` with the given arguments etc.

I did have some issues but searching on SO, google, django docs etc, I've got the command working fine.

EXCEPT when I input a negative temperature...

Then I get the following error

```
Usage: C:\test\manage.py create_raw_data [options] 

Creates a RawData object. Usage:  create_raw_data owner_id temperature [--save]

C:\test\manage.py: error: no such option: -5
```

The code I have for parsing the args is like this

```
for index, item in enumerate(args):
    if index == 0:
        owner_id = int(item)
    else index == 1:
        temp = int(item)
```

I put a `print(args)` as the 1st line inside `Handle` but it seems the control is not even reaching here.

I'm not sure what is wrong... please help...

Thanks a lot

Comment: search for 'django escaping characters' - the minus sign is seen as an indicator of an option, you have to tell django that it's not an option but one of your arguments

Comment: what happens if you escape the - with a backslash? `\-5`

Comment: I could not get the custom command to debug properly. Figured that out and along with hint from @KevinDTimm, it seems the issue is with parse_args method of optparse. 

I've read in a number of places that though optparse is deprecated and instead argparse is recommended, django recommends using optparse since that is what it uses. 

Long story short, the link at [link](http://objectmix.com/python/211112-getopt-negative-numbers.html) suggested a few alternatives and using **create_raw_data 1 -- -5** works as expected. So I did get a workaround. 

Thanks.

Comment: @dm03514 - i tried \-5 first thing. that gives

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\-5'

Comment: since the issue is sorted.. should i remove the question or somehow mark it answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the issue fixed so providing an answer to others who may come across this.

The issue was with parse_args method of optparse. I've read in a number of places that though optparse is deprecated and instead argparse is recommended, django recommends using optparse since that is what it uses. Long story short, the link at link suggested a few alternatives and using `create_raw_data 1 -- -5` works as expected. So I did get a workaround. Thanks.